# Why is correct .kv code using screenmanager not working when i put it in an external .kv file?

Tags: python, kivy

Perfectly functional code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder

from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, NoTransition

Builder.load_string("""
#:kivy 1.8

<StartScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        Label:
            text: "Press Button to"
        Button:
            text: "Start Server"
            on_press:
                root.start_server()
                root.manager.current='stopscreen'

<StopScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        Label:
            text: "Press Button to"
        Button:
            text: "Stop Server"
            on_press:
                root.stop_server()
                root.manager.current='startscreen'
""")

class StartScreen(Screen): 
    def start_server(self):
        print('Server started.')


class StopScreen(Screen):  
    def stop_server(self):
        print('Server stopped.')


sm = ScreenManager(transition=NoTransition())
sm.add_widget(StartScreen(name='startscreen'))
sm.add_widget(StopScreen(name='stopscreen'))


class MySpecialApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return sm


MySpecialApp().run()
```

Now, according to the Kivy Docs, it should be possible to put the string loaded at the beginning of this code into an external file, myspecial.kv
As soon as i do that, my screen is left blank, no buttons, no text. Why is that, and how can i get this to work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `myspecial.kv` file is loaded when the app is started, but you initialise your widgets before that. At the point where you run `sm = ScreenManager(transition=NoTransition())`, the kv hasn't yet been loaded, and so the ScreenManager does not have the expected styling.

You should instead create your widgets within the `build` method. The kv file is loaded before this method is run, so everything should behave fine.

Answer (score 1):

**main.py**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen


class StartScreen(Screen): 
    def start_server(self):
        print('Server started.')


class StopScreen(Screen):  
    def stop_server(self):
        print('Server stopped.')


class RootScreen(ScreenManager):
    pass


class MySpecialApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return RootScreen()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MySpecialApp().run()
```

**myspecial.kv**

```
<RootScreen>:
    StartScreen:
    StopScreen:


<StartScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        Label:
            text: "Press Button to"
        Button:
            text: "Start Server"
            on_press:
                root.start_server()
                root.manager.current='stopscreen'


<StopScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        Label:
            text: "Press Button to"
        Button:
            text: "Stop Server"
            on_press:
                root.stop_server()
                root.manager.current='startscreen'
```